# Unable to find how "undefined" is getting printed in Example

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor

I have got a simple example where I am using Constructor function to create object and print --

1. Object
2. Name property via function.

However, along with the 2 items I am getting `undefined` also printed. I don't know how this is getting printed in outcome. Please, someone help in understanding how the hell is this `undefined` also getting printed as outcome!

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body> 
        <script>
            var alpha = function(name, age) {
                this.name = name;
                this.age = age; 
                this.printName = function() {
                    console.log(this.name);
                }
            };

            var obj1 = new alpha("Jane", 23);
 
            console.log(obj1);
            console.log(obj1.printName());

        </script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: `.printName` returns nothing, that's why it's evaluated to `undefined`, simple as that. Remember, "printing/logging" doesn't mean "returning".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please, someone help in understanding how the hell is this 'undefined' also getting printed as outcome!**

You're getting `undefined` printed as outcome because the method `this.printName` returns nothing, which prompts the `Developer Tools console` to print `undefined` after printing the actual result when the method is invoked.

The solution is to return the value instead of printing.

```
var alpha = function(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age; 
  this.printName = function() {
    return this.name;
  }
};

var obj1 = new alpha("Jane", 23);

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj1.printName());
```

Answer (score 2):

> However, along with the 2 items I am getting undefined also printed.
>   I don't know how this is getting printed in outcome

This is the **returned-value** of `console.log`.

`printName` is correctly printing *Jane* via a `console.log`

You can change your `printName` method to

```
this.printName = function(){
    return this.name;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var alpha = function(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.printName = function() {
    return this.name;
  }
};

var obj1 = new alpha("Jane", 23);

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj1.printName());
```